# Remoting with AIR and Weborb for Java

Tags: apache-flex, air, weborb

I am trying to do remoting with AIR with weborb for Java in Server-side.

I saw people using endpoint for blazeds http://IP:PORT/blazeds/messagebroker/amf

Can any one please tell me what i should give as end point for weborb for java.

I tried following, But its not working. Any help would be of greatly appreciated.

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;       
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.remoting.mxml.RemoteObject;

        public function init():void
        {
            var remote:RemoteObject =new RemoteObject();
            remote.destination = "Test";
            **remote.endpoint = "https://localhost:5480/foo/weborb.wo"**
            remote.addEventListener("result", onResult);
            remote.addEventListener("fault", onFault);
            remote.sayHello();
        }
        public function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void {
            var result:Object = (event as ResultEvent).result as Object ;
            Alert.show(result.toString());

        }

        public function onFault(event:FaultEvent):void {
            Alert.show(event.fault.faultDetail);
            //Alert.show("Failed");
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to remove my question. This code works.I forgot to add serviceconfig.xml in my FlexBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will be working fine as such. Only thing I forgot to add is service-config.xml in FlexBUilder.